# how does method POST processes/excecutes in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, redirect, header

I am building a web application, I am having lots of confusion when ever I use POST method.

Lets say I have the below code

```
<?php
$abc = 'abc';
if(some condition){
   $abc = 'xyz';
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  header("Location:http://someexample.php/$abc");
  die();
}
?>

<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="textinput" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  <input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear" />
</form>
```

so as per my understanding, If I am not wrong. 
When I click the SUBMIT / CLEAR button. The PHP file reloads the self page first before redirecting it to the header location.

If I am right. Is there any other way to avoid multiple redirects when we are working on big PHP files. When I have multiple SUBMIT button.

thank you in advance

Comment: What's wrong with this method?

Comment: I have almost 6 input submits. and each one redirect to the same page and then find outs its next page. that seems like every time it loads two pages..

Comment: as written, this code will NOT redirect as you've performed output BEFORE calling `header()`.

Comment: @yellowandred You are outputting before your header. It's `echo` or `header`. Take your pick. You can however implement both, yet in an `if` condition. You will get the following error `headers already sent`.

Comment: you define separate action for each form it will be easier to handle ...

Comment: @yellowandred If you have (almost) 6 input submits, then I suggest you post your actual code, if that's what you're having a hard time with.

Comment: @yellowandred BTW, in order to make your form work and using either `echo` **"or"** `header` but just not at the same time,  you will need to include the closing `)` **in** `if(isset($_POST['submit']){` which should read as `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Comment: @fred, thank you for your support. The code was not my problem. I was having confusing with the execution and redirection. avoiding AJAX

Comment: Ok, is this a **"New Trend"**, where OPs change their code "AFTER" an answer was accepted? I don't get it. (*This is happening quite often lately*).

Comment: @yellowandred You're very much welcome, however I don't understand why you didn't post your original code in the first place, and you edited your question after you accepted an answer. Your new code (edit) is a completely different scenario.

Comment: @Fred, My intention was not to hide the code, I had 400 lines of codes in almost the above manner but in my code, I had almost 6 input submits. which redirects to different places after some calculations in the top..

first time I

Comment: I edited the question thinking that the question might mislead future readers. Ajax method and the code what Matt had put was helpful.

Comment: @yellowandred Regarding your edit, I need to point something out here, and I think/hope that you will agree with me on this. 
It's not fair to others who stand at being downvoted for answers they might have given, because they were not aware of the actual intent; I have seen this happen many times. In the future, I suggest you post your actual code that you are having problems with. Otherwise, one risks in getting a downvote for nothing.

Comment: @yellowandred There was a very similar question asked this morning on the same problem, someone gave an answer and was downvoted; why, well because of the original intent being omitted from the question. Not fair at all, and I hope you agree with me. How would you like to get downvoted for nothing? There... *I rest my case*. Point in check right? (*wink*)

Comment: @yellowandred Thanks (and you're welcome), many will appreciate it, including myself. Cheers, (*Peace*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms always post to the "action" attribute in it. If you don't want it to post to self, put your form opening tag as `<form action="someexample.php" method="post">`. The result will be the POST data being sent to `someexample.php` instead of to the same page as the form.

If you're looking into multiple form options on one page without redirect, take a look into AJAX submits.

The idea would be to send over the form to your receiving file, process the POST data, and return whatever you wanted returned from that process. For example:

```
$("form").submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent the file submitting
    var formData = $(this).serialize(); //process the form into an array for submission
    $.ajax({
        url: "receiver.php", //the url of the receiving file
        type: "post", //setting method to post
        data: formData, //set the data being sent to the form contents
        success: function(response) {
            $("div").html(response); //set the receiving div to the html you echo'd in the php document
        }
    });
});
```

Your `receiver.php` file can look exactly the same as a normal PHP document receiving POST data, so `<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {} ?>` will still work exactly as you're expecting, without the page redirects! This solution does require [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js) though.

Edit:

To deal with the questions update of `if(criteria) { $abc = 'xyz'; }` there are a couple of suggestions.

To keep the asynchronous approach, go with `$_SESSION` variables. You could set them using the `receiver.php` and deal with them in the starting document.

To go back to a standard submission method onto the same document, either break your multiple options into radio inputs, checkboxes, or separate forms.

So:

```
<input type="radio" name="method" value="submit" />
<input type="radio" name="method" value="clear" />
```

That way you can choose what method to submit there.

Or you can break them into forms:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear" />
</form>
```

Finally, you could change the value of a hidden input on click if you wanted to change between submit and clear, so:

The HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="method" name="method" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
    <input type="submit" id="clear" value="clear" name="clear" />
</form>
```

The jQuery:

```
$("#submit").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#method").val("clear"); //set the method to clear
    $("form").submit(); //submit the form normally
});
$("#clear").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#method").val("submit");
    $("form").submit();
});
```

The PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //do something
} elseif(isset($_POST['clear'])) {
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with multiple redirects: this is how traditional web works.

You may get reduce the number of redirects by using AJAX calls though.

Some notes on your pseudo-code:

- it is quite useless to echo anything before `Location` header: noone is supposed to read the message. Not to mention that no output is allowed before headers.
- `http://` in front of address allowed only in case of fully qualified URI.

so, the code actually have to be

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  header("Location: someexample.php");
  die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Also, the main reason you should redirect after a POST call, is that the user will not send the form over and over again in case he try to reload the page for any reason.

Comment: Enlightnen me; how can your code actually work, in conjunction with the OP's form? I can't make any sense of it, or is it just me? (It keeps throwing errors)

Comment: Ok, I figured out why your code threw me an error. You forgot to include the closing `)` in `if(isset($_POST['submit']){` which should have read `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` - *"Even the pros make mistakes, every once in a while."* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are basically redirecting your request to another page. Instead of redirecting the page using header you should use the action attribute of the form.

```
<form method="POST" action="yourexample.php" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="textinput" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
<input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear" />
</form>
```

the form will redirect you to the second page. If you do not want to reload your page at all you should use ajax. You can use jquery and post your values to another page buy creating a function. In this case your form tag should not have the action attribute or you 
should use **preventDefault** method.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: data,
success: success,
dataType: dataType
});
});
```

url will be the name of the page to which you want to redirect the user. 
The data will be your form. You can use the .serialize() method to get your form data.

```
var data = $("myForm").serialize();
```

In success you can define a function on what to do in case of successful result.